# Connecting Web Parts - No Provider Schema

Tags: 2013, web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

This is in an on-premise SP 2013 environment

I am trying to connect a list view web part to a data form web part. (I want the list view web part to get filter values from the data form webpart). SharePoint's UI provides an option to "get filter values from" the data form webpart, but upon selecting this option I always get a "No Provider Schema" message. I have checked my ULS logs and no errors are being thrown related to this action.

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to fix it?

Alternatively, could I go about making the connection in the XSLT code in SharePoint Designer? (2013 mind you). Even if I could just fetch an ID parameter from the URL of the page for use in the filter, that would help me out. I have spent a great deal of time attempting to learn how to do this with no real success so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update - I was confused over how web part connections work.

Rather than connecting my list view web part to a data form web part, I needed to connect my list view web part to a filter web part. This enabled me to successfully connect the web part and pass in parameters from the page URL. Additionally, I needed to mark a checkbox to enable server-side rendering to get it to work in my particular case.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Can u proved details as to how you solved it? did you use the query string filter?

Comment: If you add a filter web part called Query String (URL) Filter. can then set it to grab any query string you want and then connect it to list view web part. Just pick the query string name for the Query String (URL) Filter (such as ID) and then connect it to your list view web part. Connections > Send Filter Values To > chose your list view web part. Connection Type > Get Filter Values From (I had to use this rather than Get Parameter) then click Configure button and choose the Consumer Field on your list that's related.

Comment: You weren't confused about how web part connections work, you were confused because something that *should* work doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

You can connect two List View Web Parts together directly but yes, you seem to need to use a Query String Filter Web Part if you're using a Data Form Web Part and a List View Web Part.

I was using a List View Web Part with another List View Web Part as a "child", connected via Send Row of Data To <> Get Filter Value From, but when I switched to a Data Form Web Part for the "parent", I could no longer connect them directly. One of many SharePoint quirks.